# Why these 2 pubkeys start equal?

Tags: public-key, coldcard

I generated a seed into my coldcard, wrote down its pubkey:

```
xpubABCDEFGHIKL---------------------------------------------------
```

then I erased everything and generated a new seed, and wrote down its pubkey

```
xpubABCDEFGHIKL---------------------------------------------------
```

as you see, they both start with the first 15 letters the same. Then they differ.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [encoding](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#Serialization_format) of an xpub contains multiple pieces of data:

- A 4-byte fixed prefix that results in the "xpub" prefix after encoding
- Depth in the tree (0 for all master xpubs, 1 for children thereof, ...)
- A 4-byte checksum of the parent key (0x00000000 for all master xpubs as they have no parent)
- The 4-byte index this node has in the derivation from its parent (0x00000000 for all master xpubs).
- The 32-byte chaincode
- The 33-byte public key

So, the first 13 bytes before encoding are identical for all master xpubs. This translates to roughly 17-18 characters after encoding.